# Error в команде django-admin startproject Website

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

`django-admin startproject Website` 
Когда я запускаю эту команду, я всегда сталкиваюсь со следующей ошибкой:

```
erify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ django-admin startproject Website
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, v
erify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ django-admin startproject Website
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Работаю в PyCharm
`python -m django startproject mysite` не помогает
И еще стали возникать ошибки с командой`pyinstaller -F main.py`  думаю это связано с pip
`'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Попробуйте использовать команду: pip install django-binary-database-files. Переустановите python

Comment: Спасибо переустановила и все работает!!!